# Crash when trying to encrypt a file with Crypto++ RSA Scheme

Tags: c++, encryption, crypto++

I have successfully used this some lines ago in my program:

```
string tmp;
    StringSource(msg, true, new PK_EncryptorFilter(*rng, *encryptor, new CryptoPP::HexEncoder(new StringSink(tmp))));
    return tmp;
```

So you know that the Crypto++ objects are well created and so.

Now I want to encrypt a whole binary file and save it to an adjacent file:

```
FileSource(file.c_str(), true, new PK_EncryptorFilter(*rng, *encryptor, new FileSink((file+".xx").c_str(), true)),true);
```

But this last line crashes with a debug error stating that *abort() has been called*.

Hunting down the error, I tried to change the second argument to the FileSource call to false, leading to the following code:

```
FileSource(file.c_str(), false, new PK_EncryptorFilter(*rng, *encryptor, new FileSink((file+".xx").c_str(), true)),true);
```

And then the error gone, but the destination file weights 0 bytes, nothing was read/wrote.

I do not know what can can the key to the problem, so, I hope someone can help a little bit.

EDIT: I am using Visual Studio 2013 Pro.

EDIT2: I hunted the error further.

This works and the file binary content is correctly printed on screen:

```
string s;
FileSource file2("C:\\test.jpg", true, new StringSink(s));
std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

But this don't work and ends with the mentioned crash.

```
string s;
FileSource file2("C:\\test.jpg", true, new PK_EncryptorFilter(*rng, *encryptor, new StringSink (s)));
std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

This is so strange since the same PK_EncryptorFilter filter is used in another method without trouble, as I stated at the beginning of the post.

Anyway, I post here my entire class, so as to get a clear idea of what is going on:

```
RSASystem::RSASystem()
{
    std::string pubkey = "...OMITED...";

    rng = new AutoSeededRandomPool;

    CryptoPP::HexDecoder decoder;
    decoder.Put((byte*)pubkey.c_str(), pubkey.size());
    decoder.MessageEnd();

    CryptoPP::HexDecoder decoder2;
    decoder2.Put((byte*)pubkey.c_str(), pubkey.size());
    decoder2.MessageEnd();

    verifier = new RSASSA_PKCS1v15_SHA_Verifier;
    encryptor = new RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor;

    verifier->AccessKey().Load(decoder);
    encryptor->AccessKey().Load(decoder2);
}

string RSASystem::encrypt(string msg)
{
    string tmp;
    StringSource(msg, true, new PK_EncryptorFilter(*rng, *encryptor, new CryptoPP::HexEncoder(new StringSink(tmp))));
    return tmp;
}

void RSASystem::encryptFile(string file)
{
    FileSource(file.c_str(), true, new PK_EncryptorFilter(*rng, *encryptor, new FileSink((file+".xx").c_str(), true)),true);
}
```

EDIT 3: After surrounding the code with try..catch() I got this error:

```
RSA/OAEP-MGF1(SHA-1): message length of 490986 exceeds the maximum of 214 for this public key
```

Which now I think can be easily solved.

Comment: Can you get the sample code to work that's offered on the Crypto++ wiki? (I'm wondering if its a library problem, and the wiki code should be good).

Comment: I'll try it in a couple of hours, or so, I am away from home now...

Comment: I know its not consolation now, but you are close to solving the issue since its only the difference between sources and sinks. It will probably be a path or filename problem. Be sure to catch a `CryptoPP::Exception` and see what happens.

Comment: I will, so maybe I get the whole thing solved. Meanwhile, you can check my last progress, weirder, if possible.

Comment: After `verifier->AccessKey().Load(decoder)` and `encryptor->AccessKey().Load(decoder2)`, call `Validate(prng, 3)`. See [Validating Keys](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Keys_and_formats#Validating_Keys) on the wiki.

Comment: `RSASSA_PKCS1v15_SHA_Verifier` and `RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor` is an odd combination. Is that intended?

Comment: Why it's an odd combination? I need a Encryptor to send secure messages to net. And a Verifier to make sure the correct server issued the commands I receive.

Comment: OK, surrounding the code with try..catch() I got this:

`RSA/OAEP-MGF1(SHA-1): message length of 490986 exceeds the maximum of 214 for this public key`

Finally something that makes sense. How I can fix this?

Comment: And moreover `encryptor->AccessKey().Validate(*rng, 3)` validates correctly.

Comment: Re: Crypto++ exception: Your message is too large (obviously). You can (1) break the message up into smaller part and operate the `RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor` in ECB like mode (not recommended); (2) encrypt the message with a symmetric cipher and then encrypt the symmetric key with `RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor`; or (3) use an Integrated Encryption Scheme that does (2) for you. For (3) you have Shoup's [`ECIES`](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Integrated_Encryption_Scheme) and DLIES/DHAES.

Comment: Re: message size: you can use `MaxPreimage` to determine the maximum size of a plain text message given a public key; and `MaxImage` to determine the maximum cipher text size given a plain text size. Functions like `FixedPlaintextLength` calls the later.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I actually found this post very useful, once you pointed to the problem. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44702/whats-the-limit-on-the-size-of-the-data-that-public-key-cryptos-can-handle

If you can, please, post an answer with your explanation and the link, and I'lll accept it.

Comment: don't even bother with (2) above or http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44702/whats-the-limit-on-the-size-of-the-data-that-public-key-cryptos-can-handle. Just use an Integrated Encryption Scheme like ECIES or DLIES/DHAES. The integrated schemes use public key crypto, utilize symmetric bulk encryption and provide the authentication tags. Because the authentication tags are built into the scheme, you will *not* need a separate signer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had already pending the encryption and security subject so I wasn't aware of the limitation on the length of the message of the RSA scheme.
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44702/whats-the-limit-on-the-size-of-the-data-that-public-key-cryptos-can-handle

So the solution passes by implementing an Integrated or Hybrid Encryption Scheme, like ECIES.

I've done this successfully with Crypto++ using: http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Integrated_Encryption_Scheme

Thanks to *jww* to point to the correct decision.

Answer (score 3):

```
FileSource(file.c_str(), false,
    new PK_EncryptorFilter(*rng, *encryptor,
        new FileSink((file+".xx").c_str(), true)
    ),
true);
```

This does not look right. <strike>`new FileSink((file+".xx").c_str()` returns a `char*`, and you need a pointer to a `Sink`</strike>. Plus, there's an extra false in there I'm not used to seeing. Something like:

```
FileSource fs1(filename, true,
    new PK_EncryptorFilter(rng, encryptor,
        new FileSink(filename, true)
   ) // PK_EncryptorFilter
); // StringSource
```

There's a couple of examples on the Crypto++ wiki. See [RSA Cryptography](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Cryptography) and [RSA Encryption Schemes](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Encryption_Schemes).

The following is an example from the Crypto++ wiki using RSA. But you can use the code for any cryptosystem that adheres to `PK_Encryptor` and `PK_Decryptor` (`Sources` (like `StringSource` and `FileSource`) and `Sinks` (like `StringSink` and `FileSink`) are also interchangeable):

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Generate keys
AutoSeededRandomPool rng;

InvertibleRSAFunction params;
params.GenerateRandomWithKeySize( rng, 1536 );

RSA::PrivateKey privateKey( params );
RSA::PublicKey publicKey( params );

string plain="RSA Encryption", cipher, recovered;

////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Encryption
RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor e( publicKey );

StringSource ss1( plain, true,
    new PK_EncryptorFilter( rng, e,
        new StringSink( cipher )
    ) // PK_EncryptorFilter
 ); // StringSource

////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Decryption
RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor d( privateKey );

StringSource ss2( cipher, true,
    new PK_DecryptorFilter( rng, d,
        new StringSink( recovered )
    ) // PK_DecryptorFilter
 ); // StringSource

assert( plain == recovered );
```

---

Also, don't use anonymous declarations. Some versions of GCC has problems with them. That is, use:

```
StringSource ss1( plain, true,
    ...
```

rather than:

```
StringSource( plain, true,
    ...
```

Comment: I dont agree with you, `new FileSink((file+".xx").c_str(), true)` returns a pointer to a sink. Is the same code as yours but replacing `filename` with `(file+".xx").c_str()`. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Dark_eye - Yes, you're right. My bad. I struck it. Thanks.

Comment: I saw your edit too late. That `false` was set to try to mitigate the error, but then is not pulling any data from the file. Which reading from the docs seems logical. http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/User_Guide:_filters.h

Comment: Right. The first false is `pumpAll`. If its false, then no data is pumped. Your problem is elsewhere. Can you also include the `Encryptor` and `Decryptor` objects? Also, are you catching Crypto++ exceptions? The `abort` could be an uncaught exception. Finally, does the key validate after loading it?

Comment: As I said at the beginning, Strings encryption and verification works flawlessly, as they are implemented earlier in the program. It seems that is some trouble with file handling.

Comment: OK. Are you writing the files with an `ofstream`, or is Crypto++ writing it? And `PWD` is not readily apparent under Visual Studio. I believe its `<proj director>/debug/win32` or similar, and *not* `<proj directory>`. Are you getting a `File Not Found` or similar during the read (or an uncaught exception)?

Comment: Crypto++ is writing it, as I passed it the path as a String only.
There's no signal that can be interpreted as a File Not Found error, but I will double check that very soon.

Comment: @jww What I don't understand here is; what if you have encryption and decryption on two different calls. On the first, you have the rng value for encryption, but in the future, maybe i.e. 10 days later, how do you recover that rng for performing decryption? This is the part that puzzles me a lot :O I'm assuming you must also save the rng value but hmm.

Comment: @Teo - In the case of RSA, each encryption usually results in a different cipher text. That's because (depending on the scheme) random padding is added so the same message does not produce the same cipher text. The property is called cipher text indistinguishability or [IND-CCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability). It is usually a desired property.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I know where you might be having problems. But I'd need to see *all* your code and not just the encryption.

I could coax a `BER Decode error` by *omitting* `encoder1.MessageEnd` and `encoder2.MessageEnd`. Apparently, I was able to read the key before it was fully written. I assume it was fully written after leaving `main` (and the destructors ran) because the file sizes looked OK with `ls`.

In the code below, the message was encrypted under `publicKey1` and then decrypted with `privateKey2` to ensure the keys were round-tripping.

```
try {

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Generate keys
    AutoSeededRandomPool rng;

    InvertibleRSAFunction params;
    params.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(rng, 1024);

    RSA::PrivateKey privateKey1(params);
    RSA::PublicKey publicKey1(privateKey1);

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Save/Load keys  
    HexEncoder encoder1(new FileSink("private-key-der.txt", true));
    HexEncoder encoder2(new FileSink("public-key-der.txt", true));

    privateKey1.Save(encoder1);
    publicKey1.Save(encoder2);

    // Must have these. Otherwise, the full key (hex encoded)
    //   is not written until destructors are run
    encoder1.MessageEnd();
    encoder2.MessageEnd();

    FileSource fs1("private-key-der.txt", true, new HexDecoder);
    FileSource fs2("public-key-der.txt", true, new HexDecoder);

    RSA::PrivateKey privateKey2;
    RSA::PublicKey publicKey2;

    privateKey2.Load(fs1);
    bool valid = privateKey2.Validate(rng, 3);
    if(!valid)
        throw Exception(Exception::OTHER_ERROR, "Failed to validate key 1");

    publicKey2.Load(fs2);
    valid = publicKey2.Validate(rng, 3);
    if(!valid)
        throw Exception(Exception::OTHER_ERROR, "Failed to validate key 2");

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Scratch
    string plain="RSA Encryption", cipher, recovered;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Encryption
    RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor encryptor(publicKey1);

    StringSource ss1(plain, true,
                     new PK_EncryptorFilter(rng, encryptor,
                                            new StringSink(cipher)
                                            ) // PK_EncryptorFilter
                     ); // StringSource

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Decryption
    RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor decryptor(privateKey2);

    StringSource ss2(cipher, true,
                     new PK_DecryptorFilter(rng, decryptor,
                                            new StringSink(recovered)
                                            ) // PK_DecryptorFilter
                     ); // StringSource

    cout << "Recovered plain text: " << recovered << endl;

} catch (const Exception& ex) {
    cerr << ex.what() << endl;
}
```

Comment: I did call to respective MessageEnd. If you recall from the first post:
    `CryptoPP::HexDecoder decoder;`
     `decoder.Put((byte*)pubkey.c_str(), pubkey.size());`
     `decoder.MessageEnd();`
    
     `CryptoPP::HexDecoder decoder2;`
     `decoder2.Put((byte*)pubkey.c_str(), pubkey.size());`
     `decoder2.MessageEnd();`

Comment: But your code has `std::string pubkey = "...OMITED..."`. So some of the interesting stuff might be omitted.